# How to receive my vars in php file (from javascript code)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, post

I have two .php files `cotiza.php`and`insertCot.php`

In cotiza.php I have some inputs and a button, the button has a `onClick` function, I take the values of my inputs and send them to the `javascript function`:

```
<button type="button" onClick="GuardacotizacionaBD(document.getElementById('pais').value, document.getElementById('proyecto').value, 
    document.getElementById('notas').value, document.getElementById('formapago').value, document.getElementById('fechaentrega').value, 
    document.getElementById('flete').value, 
    document.getElementById('instalacion').value,
    document.getElementById('venta').value, 
    document.getElementById('total').value);">Realizar</button> //It works, I have not problem with this
```

in my function I get the values and I send them to `insertaCot.php`

```
function  GuardacotizacionaBD (pais, proyecto, notas, formapago, fechaentrega, flete, instalacion, venta, total)
{
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","insertaCot.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("pais="+pais+"&proyecto="+proyecto);

location.reload(true)
}
```

In insertaCot.php I receive them: To try to do an INSERT to a table on MySql

```
<?
include('conexion.php');
$coninsert=conexion();

$pais= $_POST['pais'];//this is line 22
$proyecto= $_POST['proyecto'];//this is line 23
//all my vars
?>
```

BUT i get this:

```
Undefined index: pais in C:\xampp\htdocs\insertaCot.php on line 22
Undefined index: proyecto in C:\xampp\htdocs\insertaCot.php on line 23
```

I print my form on insertCot, but it doesn't have values:

```
Array
(
)
```

**Any idea about what could i do?**

I have the same dimamic in 2 `.php` files and the work.

**thank you**

Comment: Show us the form HTML code please.

Comment: `alert(pais)` in your JS code. if that's null, then your JS code and/or html is faulty somehow.

Comment: I did it, and i have the value of all my vars! (pais, proyecto...) But I'm not recieving them on the next php file (insertcot.php) @MarcB

Comment: then check the PHP code. `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], $_POST)` and see what's really coming in.

Comment: It'S empty! @MarcB ... Ammmm So... what could I do?

Comment: put this in your PHP code and see what you get:

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_REQUEST);
echo "</pre>";
die;

Comment: It's empty. I have nothing! @Len_D

Comment: You can check into the console what actually you are sending to server, you can see your request, the parameters are being send and the response. You will be also able to see the error if any.